# Why would Model::all() work, but not Model::find($id)?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Eloquent in Laravel. I have a basic controller and model, and I'm doing this in my controller:

```php
class TeamController extends Controller
{

    public function getTeam($id)
    {
        // $id is primary key
        // echo $id displays 1 
        // id 1 exists in database
        // Doesn't work, returns empty json object
        return response()->json(Team::find($id));

        // Works, returns all teams as expected
        return response()->json(Team::all());
    }

}
```

As described in the comments in the code, `Team::find($id)` returns an empty Json object, but `Team::all()` returns all as expected.
`Team::where('name', 'Test Team')` also doesn't work, even though those are in the database.

I've been looking at this for a while but I must be missing something simple - does anyone have any ideas on what might be going on here?

Edit: here is the Team model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Team extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'teams';

 // public static function __callStatic($method, $args) 
 //    {
 //        if ($method == 'findValidById') {
 //
 //            $team = Team::find($args[0]);
 //           
 //            if ($team)
 //            {
 //             return $team;
 //            }
 //            throw new \Exception('The specified team does not exist', 400);
 //        }
 //    }

    protected $casts = [
        'admin_id' => 'int'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'logo',
        'admin_id',
        'team_key'
    ];
}
```

And this is the table, if it's any help:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIVfw.png)

Comment: Did you try `Team::where('name', 'Test Team')->first();` ?

Comment: Check for primary key in your table as `return response()->json(Team::find($id));` will return data based on primary key

Comment: For more info https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Comment: What's the result of `dd(Team::find($id));`?

Comment: can you check `dd($id)` ? just make sure

Comment: What if $id is a string?

Comment: @LeenaPatel I did try `first()`, but I get an error for calling it on null, since nothing was found.

Comment: @LeenaPatel and yep, id is sent as the primary key on my database. I'm  running a local database and using HeidiSQL.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir `dd(Team::find($id))` is null, and `dd($id)` is "1"

Comment: Please log the query: `\DB::enableQueryLog(); Team::find($id); dd(\DB::getQueryLog());`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir It just logs: `[]`

Comment: Are you using multiple database connections?

Comment: Well, I've got one connection, with a couple of databases, but it's connected to the correct database. Strangely I have another Controller, User, where this works correctly. They are both set up the same as far as I can see.

Comment: What happens when you log the other query? `\DB::enableQueryLog(); Team::all(); dd(\DB::getQueryLog());`

Comment: `array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from `teams`"
    "bindings" => []
    "time" => 4.0
  ]
]` Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: Please post your `Team` model.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I've edited the question to include the model, not much in it

Comment: what result `\DB::enableQueryLog(); Team::find(1); dd(\DB::getQueryLog());` give?

Comment: try using `$id = intval($id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I messed up... 
I realised after commenting out the `_callStatic()` function in the model when adding it to the question (thanks @JonasStaudenmeir)  that I was never returning `parent::_callStatic()`. I'd forgotten that was even there as I'm not using it now.

Thank you everyone for your help, I don't have enough rep to vote your comments but thanks.

I'm not sure why all() still worked but not where() or find().

Comment: `all()` was still working because it's defined in the `Model` class and doesn't require `__callStatic()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use find() method, the team table has to primary field that named "id"

You should check there is named "id" that primary field on the table. If it is there, you should check if it is any data on the table with value of $id parameter.

If there is no any problem on the above states, You can use Model injection method instead of find() method.

Please review following code;

// Route

```
// The {team} parameter is primary id of team table. For need of a team data, the url must be following;
// domainn.com/get-team/1
Route::get('get-team/{team}', 'TeamController@getTeam')->name('get_team');
```

// Controller

```
public function getTeam(Team $team)
{
        // The team parameter is the given Team model instance.
        // We can use directly 
        return response()->json($team);
}
```

I hope on the above my answers helps to you.

Comment: Hey thanks, unfortunately this doesn't help. I have a column named id which is the primary key. Also, Team::where() doesn't work either, so I don't think this issue is with the primary key, or at least not only with that.